# SQL Server CE GROUP BY exception

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have the following code to query my database

```
SELECT U.Name, U.Date, Max(I.Amount) 
  FROM Users AS U,Installments AS I 
  GROUP BY I.ID 
  HAVING (Max(I.Sr) = 40 AND U.ID = I.ID)
```

It generates exception saying

> *In aggregate and grouping expressions the SELECT clause can
>   contain only aggregate and grouping expressions [SELECT clause
>   =U.Name]*

Also I have tried `GROUP BY U.ID, I.ID` but the same problem exists

Please tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to group by U.Name and U.Date for the aggregate to work appropriately.

Comment: BUT GROUP BY U.name is a nchar and nchar are not allowed in GROUP BY as said by microsoft

Comment: @user1375948: according [to the MSDN documentation on GROUP BY for SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173245%28v=sql.100%29), only columns of type `ntext` and `image` are not supported in `GROUP BY` expressions - `nchar` shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead:

```
  SELECT 
      U.Name, U.Date, Max(I.Amount) 
  FROM 
      Users AS U
  INNER JOIN 
      Installments AS I ON U.ID = I.ID
  GROUP BY 
      U.Name, U.Date
  HAVING 
      MAX(I.Sr) = 40
```

What have I done?

- use the proper ANSI `INNER JOIN` syntax and specify the JOIN condition there, where it belongs
- `GROUP BY` must be applied to all columns in your `SELECT` list of columns that aren't aggregated
- `HAVING` should only have a simple condition - don't define `JOIN` conditions or anything here!

According [to the MSDN documentation on GROUP BY for SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173245%28v=sql.100%29), only columns of type `ntext` and `image` are not supported in `GROUP BY` expressions - `nchar` shouldn't be a problem